# ggplotly facet_wrap don't display some subplots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, ggplotly

I am trying to make a ggplot with facet_wrap and for some reason some subplots don't display and appear blank some of the time.

```
library(plotly)
peak_season <- drop_na(read_csv(url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/wb8qmrcul197ypp/peak_season.csv?raw=1")))
    
ggplotly(
  ggplot(data = peak_season, aes(x = overall, frame = age)) +
    geom_bar(position = "identity") + facet_wrap(~league_name_clean)
)
# Need to add position = "identity" due to a well known bug in ggplotly and geom_bar.
```

[image: Image of missing plots]

The data is reachable to make the plot, as shown in this image.
For Spain Primera Division there is definitely data for players in age 20.

```
ggplotly(
  ggplot(data = peak_season %>% filter(league_name_clean == "Spain Primera Division"), aes(x = overall, frame = age)) +
    geom_bar(position = "identity") + facet_wrap(~league_name_clean)
    )
# Just added a filter
```

[image: Only the plot of one league]

I made it work with gganimate, but I want my users to be able to have control and explore the data shown.

```
library(gganimate)    
ggplot(data = peak_season, aes(x = overall)) +
      geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) + facet_wrap(~league_name_clean) +
      transition_states(age, state_length = 1) +
      view_follow(fixed_y = TRUE) +
      labs(title = "Player peak age by league",
           y = "No. of players",
           subtitle = "Age: {closest_state}")
```

[image: gganimate]

I tried using RStudio Cloud to roll out a bug in my computer but it happens the same.

Any ideas why this happens?

Thanks,

Comment: Just a comment on your `# Need to add position = "identity" due to a well known bug in ggplotly and geom_bar.` It's not a bug. The default is `position = "stack"` for unaggregated data. For pre-aggregated data you use `position = "identity"` or you can use `geom_col()` instead of `geom_bar()` . A "bug" implies something broken that needs fixing, which isn't the case.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
I have seen few posts mentioning this as a "bug" so I believed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that might find this in the future, I think ggplotly isn't powerful enough to manage calculating  so many plots + the frequencies for each overall - age - league, so I had to calculate it beforehand.

```
t <- peak_season %>%
  select(overall, age, league_name_clean) %>%
  table() %>%
  as_tibble

ggplotly(
  ggplot(data = t, aes(x = Overall, y = Count, frame = age)) +
    scale_x_discrete(breaks = seq(40, 100, by = 5)) +
    geom_col(position = "identity") + facet_wrap(~league_name_clean)
  )
```

[image: working ggplotly]